# How to call javascript variables which is "like class"

Tags: javascript, class, variables, call

I have a class like this:

```
label = 
{
   car1 = "Chevrolet Camaro",
   car2 = "Ford Mustang",
   car3 = "Dodge Challenger"
}
```

When I need to get a label, I use this method:

```
function getLabel(name)
{
   switch (name.ToLowerCase())
   {
      case "car1":
         return label.car1;
         break;
      case "car2":
         return label.car2;
         break;
      case "car3":
         return label.car3;
         break;
   }
}
```

This function is OK for few rows, but if I have so many rows, is there any way to handle this? Is there any way like:

```
function getLabel(name)
{
   text = name.ToLowerCase();
   return label.text;
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: is variable `label` is a kind of json?  What is the format?

Comment: Use bracket notation: `return label[ name.toLowerCase() ];`

Comment: are you sure it isn't `label = {  car1 : "Chevrolet Camaro",`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the members of an object using a string like this:

```
function getLabel(name)
{
   var text = name.ToLowerCase();
   return label[text];
}
```

**Further Reading**

- [Property Accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a car object for easy get it's properties, like this:

```
function carObj(label, name){
  this.label = label;
  this.name = name;
}

var cars = new Array(
        new carObj('car1','Chevrolet Camaro'),
        new carObj('car2','Ford Mustang'),
        new carObj('car3','Dodge Challenger')
        );

function getCarName(label){
   for(var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++){
       if(cars[i].label == label){
          return cars.name;
       }
   }
   return '';
}
```

Comment: "for" loop will let the speed slow

Comment: This is the example. I mean mention as create an object in javascript.